# Add a tuple to a list of tuples

Tags: python

I am trying to automate few of my DBA tasks using python3.

```
x = "       @@Hostname: host1"
y = "@@innodb_buffer_pool_size: 1"
z = "  @@Max_connections: 150"
op = {}
a = tuple(x.split(':'))
b = tuple(y.split(':'))
c = tuple(z.split(':'))
host=""
if (a[0].strip()).lower() == "@@hostname" and (a[1].strip()).lower() not in op:
    host = a[1].strip()
    op[host] = []
if (b[0].strip()).lower() == "@@innodb_buffer_pool_size" and int(b[1].lstrip())<2:
    #z = b[0].strip().lstrip('@@'),b[1].strip()
    op[host].append((b[0].strip().lstrip('@@'),b[1].strip()))
if (c[0].strip()).lower() == "@@Max_connections" and int(c[1].lstrip())<152:
    op[host].append((c[0].strip().lstrip('@@'),c[1].strip()))   
#elif (a[0].strip()).lower() == "@@log_bin" and int(a[1].strip()) == 0:
 #   op[host].append(tuple((a[0].strip()).lstrip('@@'),a[1].strip()))
#elif (a[0].strip()).lower() == "@@expire_logs_days" and int(a[1].strip()) == 0:
 #   op[host].append(tuple((a[0].strip()).lstrip('@@'),a[1].strip()))
#else:
 #   pass
#print (c)
print (op)
```

Output i am getting:

```
{'host1': [('innodb_buffer_pool_size', '1')]}
```

Output i am expecting:

```
{'host1': [('innodb_buffer_pool_size', '1'),('max_connections','150')]}
```

If you look at my the code, my first append statement appends tuple to an empty list.
But my second append is not appending to the tuple to the list . 
I cannot understand why this behaviour since this first python project and what should be done to append a tuple to an existing list for a specific key in a dictionary.

This is only part of the script, I am trying to iterate through several files and construct a list of tuples for each host with each unique host being the key, hence constructing a dictionary.
Thanks

Comment: Typo. Use: `if (c[0].strip()).lower() == "@@max_connections" and ..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have this kind of case, leanr to debug and split your code, here the problem from the if using `Max_connections`  because that's the one missing

When printing the 2 conditions we have

```
print((c[0].strip()).lower() == "@@Max_connections", int(c[1].lstrip()) < 152)  # False True
```

Then looking further at the first,  you set the value as lowercase but your testing stirng contains an uppercase : not valie

Correction

```
if (c[0].strip()).lower() == "@@max_connections" and int(c[1].lstrip()) < 152:
```

Comment: If it's typo, isn't it better to close this as off-topic?

Comment: OMG..thats one of the silliest mistakes of 2020 i guess ..

Comment: @udhayandharmalingam don't feel bad, we all make this kind of silly mistake xD

Comment: @udhayandharmalingam you can accept the answer so ;) Green tick ;)